# Need some help converting to math.div

Tags: css, math, sass

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can convert this to use math.div

```
@function ar($width, $height, $context: 100) {
    @return #{$height / ($width / $context) + "%"};
}
```

I have an equation within an equation, and I thought maybe this

```
@function ar($width, $height, $context: 100) {
    @return #{math.div($height, (#math.div($width, $context))) + "%"};
}
```

But this doesn't work, my output example should be 31.25%, but it's coming out as 5/0.16%. Could someone help me out and offer a little advice.

Comment: That second `#` looks weird to me. Have you tried `@return #{math.div($height, (math.div($width, $context))) + "%"};`?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @JSON Derulo, this is the correct way to do it.

```
@return #{math.div($height, (math.div($width, $context))) + "%"};
```